# Write a ~ATH Interpreter

Tags: code-golf, interpreter

The popular webcomic [Homestuck](http://www.mspaintadventures.com) makes use of a programming language called `~ATH` to destroy universes. While this code golf challenge is **not** to write a program to annihilate our existence, we will be destroying some more tame (albeit less interesting) entities: *variables*.

`~ATH` (pronounced "til death," notice how `~ath` is "tilde ath") works by creating a variable called `THIS`, executing a command with `EXECUTE`, and finishing the program with `THIS.DIE()`. A wiki page for the language's use in Homestuck can be found [here](http://mspaintadventures.wikia.com/wiki/~ATH). The goal of this challenge will be to create a `~ATH` interpreter.

For the sake of the challenge, I'm going to create some details of `~ATH` that don't really exist but make it (somewhat) useful.

- The language will only work with integers, which are declared with `import <variable name>;`. The variable will automatically be set to a value of 0. Only one variable at a time can be imported.
- A variable `x` can be copied by writing `bifurcate x[y,z];`, which will delete the variable `x` and replace it with identical variables `y` and `z`. Note that it cannot create a variable with the same name as the one deleted. Essentially, a variable is renamed, then a copy of the variable with a different name is created. This seems like a stupid feature, but stupidity is [very](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/?s=6&p=003552) deeply [ingrained](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/?s=6&p=005289) in Homestuck.
- The syntax for writing a program that executes code on `x` is `~ATH(x){EXECUTE(<code>)}`. If you want to execute code on two variables simultaneously, the code becomes nested, like this: `~ATH(x){~ATH(y){EXECUTE(<code>)}}`. All commands in `<code>` will be executed on both `x` and `y`.
- Now let's move onto commands. `+` increments relevant variable(s) by 1 and `-` decrements them by 1. And... that's it.
- The final feature of `~ATH` is that it kills whatever it works with. Variables are printed in the format `<name>=<value>` (followed by a newline) at the command `[<name>].DIE();`. Afterwards, the program prints the word `DIE <name>` and a newline a number of times equal to the absolute value of the value of the variable. When variables are killed simultaneously with `[<name1>,<name2>].DIE();` (you can have as many variables killed as you want, so long as they exist), the `DIE()` command is executed on the variables sequentially.

**Example programs**

Program 1:

```
import sollux;                  //calls variable "sollux"
import eridan;                  //calls variable "eridan"
~ATH(sollux){EXECUTE(--)}       //sets the value of "sollux" to -2
~ATH(eridan){EXECUTE(+++++)}    //sets the value of "eridan" to 5
[sollux].DIE();                 //kills "sollux", prints "DIE sollux" twice
~ATH(eridan){EXECUTE(+)}        //sets the value of "eridan" to 6
[eridan].DIE();                 //kills "eridan", prints "DIE eridan" 6 times
```

Output:

```
sollux=-2
DIE sollux
DIE sollux
eridan=6
DIE eridan
DIE eridan
DIE eridan
DIE eridan
DIE eridan
DIE eridan
```

Program 2:

```
import THIS;                    //calls variable "THIS"
~ATH(THIS){EXECUTE(++++)}       //sets the value of "THIS" to 4
bifurcate THIS[THIS1,THIS2];    //deletes "THIS", creates variables "THIS1" and "THIS2" both equal to 4
~ATH(THIS1){EXECUTE(++)}        //sets the value of "THIS1" to 6
[THIS1,THIS2].DIE();            //kills "THIS1" and "THIS2", prints "DIE THIS1" 6 times then "DIE THIS2" 4 times

import THAT;                                         //calls variable "THAT"
bifurcate THAT[THESE,THOSE];                         //deletes "THAT", creates variables "THESE" and "THOSE"
~ATH(THESE){~ATH(THOSE){EXECUTE(+++)}EXECUTE(++)}    //sets the value of "THESE" and "THOSE" to 3, then sets the value of "THESE" to 5
[THESE,THOSE].DIE();                                 //kills "THESE" and "THOSE", prints "DIE THESE" 5 times then "DIE THOSE" 3 times
```

Output:

```
THIS1=6
DIE THIS1
DIE THIS1
DIE THIS1
DIE THIS1
DIE THIS1
DIE THIS1
THIS2=4
DIE THIS2
DIE THIS2
DIE THIS2
DIE THIS2
THESE=5
DIE THESE
DIE THESE
DIE THESE
DIE THESE
DIE THESE
THOSE=3
DIE THOSE
DIE THOSE
DIE THOSE
```

---

This is code golf, so standard rules apply. Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Til death. I see what you did there.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I gotta pass the credit to Andrew Hussie (the guy who writes Homestuck) for coming up with the name.

Comment: @ the downvoters, would you mind sharing what you think could be improved?

Comment: Should the interpreter be pedantic about semicolons on line-endings? or can it just ignore their existence or lack thereof?

Comment: Also, does it *have* to function like a REPL or can we read from a file?

Comment: Is case sensitivity important everywhere or just in output?

Comment: @sysreq `~ATH` uses semicolons as line-endings for the `import`, `bifurcate`, and `DIE` commands. Both REPL and files are fine. Case sensitivity is required in both the input and the output (I'm trying to match the actual `~ATH` as much as possible).

Comment: Can we assume that EXECUTE statements like `{EXECUTE(+-++--+--)}` are *not* valid syntax and should be ignored?

Comment: @sysreq Without `~ATH(<name>)`, those statements are not valid syntax. However, with `~ATH(<name>)`, that statement would decrement the variable by 1.

Comment: the last line in program 2 doesn't end in a semicolon, but it should. I just spent 15 minutes refactoring my parser to figure out why it was recording values incorrectly, but it was a *missing semicolon.* I never thought I'd fall for one of those :-(

Comment: Also, the wiki's description of the language is wildly different (from a bare syntax perspective) from what's described here; I assume it's o.k. if I use *strictly* your spec?

Comment: @sysreq I had to change a few things so the language would actually *do* something in real life, pecs I described are fine.

Comment: I'm honestly surprised this question hasn't gotten more responses, and even more surprised there's no horde of Perl wizards armed with regexy wands of magic

Comment: Maybe it's because the final product is rather large or that after all, this is an interpreter for a *fake* language that doesn't exist in the human world.

Comment: That means I maintain the *only* interpreter for a fictional language from a fictional universe with a large nerd fanbase. Makes me want to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.7.6, <s>1244</s> <s>1308</s> <s>1265</s> <s>1253</s> <s>1073</s> <s>1072</s> <s>1071</s> <s>1065</s> <s>1064</s> 1063 bytes

Alright, I'm not breaking any records here but this is about the smallest Python will go insofar as reading input all at once from a file rather than sequentially over time. I'll try to one-up this later in a different language (and an interpreter, not just a parser). Until then, enjoy the disgustingly horrid monstrosity.

*Note*: opens a file called `t` in the working directory. To make it open a command line argument, add `import sys` to the top of the file and change `'t'` to `sys.argv[1]`

```python
n=s='\n';m=',';X='[';Y=']';c=';';A='~ATH';D='import';b,g,k=[],[],[];r=range;l=len;f=open('t','r').read().split(n)
def d(j,u):
 p=[]
 for e in j:
  if e!=u:p.append(e)
 return''.join(p)
for h in r(l(f)):f[h]=f[h].split('//')[0].split()
while[]in f:f.remove([])
for h in r(l(f)):
 i=f[h]
 if i[0]==D and l(i)==2and i[1][l(i[1])-1]==c and d(i[1],c)not in b:g.append(0);b.append(d(i[1],c))
 elif i[0].startswith(A):
  i=i[0].split('){')
  for e in r(l(i)):
   if i[e].startswith(A):
    i[e]=i[e].split('(')
    if i[0][1]in b:g[b.index(i[0][1])]+=(i[1].count('+')-i[1].count('-'))
 elif i[0].startswith('bifurcate')and l(i)==2and i[1][l(i[1])-1]==c:
  i=i[1].split(X)
  if i[0] in b:
   z=d(d(i[1],c),Y).split(m)
   for e in r(l(z)):g.append(g[b.index(i[0])]);b.append(z[e])
   g.remove(g[b.index(i[0])]);b.remove(i[0])
 elif i[0].startswith(X)and i[0].endswith('.DIE();')and l(i)==1:
  z=d(i[0],X).split(Y)[0].split(m)
  for e in r(l(z)):
   k.append((z[e],g[b.index(z[e])]))
for e in r(l(k)):k0=k[e][0];k1=k[e][1];s+=k0+'='+str(k1)+n+('DIE '+k0+n)*abs(k1)
print s
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, <s>447</s> <s>475</s> <s>463</s> 443 bytes

```python
exec("eNp1UUtrAjEQvu+vCEshiYnrxl7KbqOUVmjvCoUkxUdiG7BRkpW2iP3tTVwrReppMsx8r4l936x9A8JXoN5kmu/2WeCxK0KjrSu8mWmEs0Ad96YI27lDPu/1is7wKqcQ0kBLenM+ty0nilu4zqnPtYCSQcXL2P2LmNvl1i9mjWlBUhwKbRt14uhHjlSvjzVy1tqswO/7AjsSpKtwIpGvt2zALqyNnkf3k/FIolb2ACjlpe2jR6lk8fAUQbKNulx7YIF1IDkqwmZlGwQpxNXGW9cASyCHZKqFVVOCoJQOEhjxABKLO7N5QGmET5qOs/Qfoqq6TGUfb3ZlgKvOnOxTwJKpDq6HSLzsVfK1k7g1iB7Hd9/JWh3T9wclkYwTlY4odP0nnvk0C3RUwj95/ZUq".decode('base64').decode('zip'))
```

It turns out zipping and encoding the program base64 still saves bytes over the normal version. For comparison, here's the normal one:

```python
import sys,re
d={}
s=sys.stdin.read()
s,n=re.subn(r"//.*?$",'',s,0,8)
s,n=re.subn(r"import (.*?);",r"d['\1']=0;",s,0,8)
s,n=re.subn(r"bifurcate (.*?)\[(.*?),(.*?)\];",r"d['\2']=d['\3']=d['\1'];del d['\1'];",s,0,8)
s,n=re.subn(r"([+-])",r"\g<1>1",s,0,8)
s,n=re.subn(r"EXECUTE\((.*?)\)",r"0\1",s,0,8)
s,n=re.subn(r"\[(.*?)\]\.DIE\(\);",r"for i in '\1'.split(','):print i+'='+`d[i]`+('\\n'+'DIE '+i)*abs(d[i])",s,0,8)
n=1
s=s[::-1]
while n:s,n=re.subn(r"\}([+-01]*);?([^}]*?)\{\)(.*?)\(HTA~",r";\g<2>0+\1=+]'\3'[d;\1",s,0,8)
exec(s[::-1])
```

Basically the "regexy wands of magic" solution that was desired. Reads in the entire program from stdin as a single string, replaces ~ATH expressions with Python expressions that do the described semantics, and exec()s the resulting string.

To see what it's doing, look at the python program the second provided test program gets translated to:

```python
d['THIS']=0;                    
0+1+1+1+1;d['THIS']+=0+1+1+1+1+0;       
d['THIS1']=d['THIS2']=d['THIS'];del d['THIS'];    
0+1+1;d['THIS1']+=0+1+1+0;        
for i in 'THIS1,THIS2'.split(','):print i+'='+`d[i]`+('\n'+'DIE '+i)*abs(d[i])            

d['THAT']=0;                                         
d['THESE']=d['THOSE']=d['THAT'];del d['THAT'];                         
0+1+1;d['THESE']+=0+1+1+00+1+1+1;d['THOSE']+=0+1+1+1+0;    
for i in 'THESE,THOSE'.split(','):print i+'='+`d[i]`+('\n'+'DIE '+i)*abs(d[i])
```

It's a good thing that `00 == 0` :P

Obviously, a few bytes could be saved by exploiting ambiguity in the rules. For instance, it isn't said what should happen in the event someone tries to `DIE()` a variable that hasn't been `import`ed, or that has already been `bifurcate`d. My guess based on the description was that there should be an error. If no error is required, I could remove the `del` statement.

EDIT: Fixed a bug that the provided test cases didn't test for. Namely, the way it was, every `~ATH` block reset the variable to zero before incrementing it. It cost me 28 bytes to fix that. If anyone sees a better way to replace `~ATH` blocks, I'd love to know it.

EDIT 2: Saved 12 bytes by unrolling the regex loop, making them all subns and letting the compression take care of the repetition.

EDIT 3: Saved 20 more bytes by replacing the inner `for` loop with a string multiplication.

Comment: Hey, finally the regexy wands of magic! I won't be able to beat this but well done!

Comment: My implementation completely ignores things not explicitly covered by the rules, which means it's okay for you to not throw an error and just ignore those cases too.

Comment: you could save some bytes by doing `import sys,re` rather than `import sys;import re`

Comment: Also, how do you actually use this? you read from `sys.stdin` but far as I can tell, termination/execution/printing never occurs because it never stops reading from `stdin`. (Testing on IDLE, 2.7.6)

Comment: syntax highlighting makes this a lot easier to read

Comment: @cat sorry i forgot to answer you ever so long ago. you run it from the command line and pipe the input into from a file: `python ~ath.py < program.~ath`